# How to fix camel-k-kit error in camel-k version 1.0.0?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I just installed camel-k 1.0.0 as described in the installation documentation and ran a simple groovy example.

I installed camel-k on a 1.17 virtual on-prem kubernetes test-cluster.

The error:

```
Error during unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER): Invalid argument
User namespaces are not enabled in /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces.
level=error msg="error parsing PID \"\": strconv.Atoi: parsing \"\": invalid syntax"
level=error msg="(unable to determine exit status)"
```

How I installed:

```
kamel install --registry sonatype.nexus3.reg. --registry-auth-username MyUsername --registry-auth-password MyPassword
```

Then I executed hello.groovy:

```
kamel run hello.groovy
```

A camel-k-kit pod is created then running after a couple of seconds into the above error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: mind opening an issue on the camel-k project page with some details about your kubernetes test cluster ?